# multiple bootstrap file requests with one include

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm buiding a single-page-application with Node, Bootstrap and Angular. In the `head` section, I've included

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/steer.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

At the end of my `body`, I've included the javascript files, like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script src="/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="/js/steer-LAB.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Everything works as expected, but for some reason, I can see that my Firefox requests 1 extra `theme.css` and 5 extra `bootstrap.min.css` copies after +- 1000ms, even though they're already received well and all after +- .

This doesn't happen in Chrome. Can anyone tell me what's happening here?

Comment: I also face this problem, and don't know why...

Comment: This even happens with raw html with bootstrap css in firefox. So that is the problem of firefox and bootstrap